# Unwanted Line Drawn by Java QuadCurve.2D

Tags: java, graphics, 2d, curve

"I am trying to draw a QuadCurve line in Java. I am able to do this when I hard code the x and y values in each line, but when I try to draw the lines from a loop I get an unwanted line on the top. I want to have it in a loop so that I can create the values in another location and feed the values to my Drawing class. I think it may be a looping issue. I "stepped into" the code and the values in the array are all correct. I am in college so any help is appreciated. Thank you!

This code works:"

```
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();          
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);

    Shape drawLine1A = new QuadCurve2D.Float(40, 450, 100, 300, 210, 180); 
    Shape drawLine2A = new QuadCurve2D.Float(210, 180, 315, 150, 390, 240);                                               
    Shape drawLine3A = new QuadCurve2D.Float(390, 240, 430, 242, 480, 245);



    g2.draw(drawLine1A);
    g2.draw(drawLine2A);
    g2.draw(drawLine3A);
```

"This code does not work correctly:"

```
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();          
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
    Shape line;

    int[] x = {40, 100, 210, 210, 315, 390, 390, 430, 480};
    int[] y = {450, 300, 180, 180, 150, 240, 240, 242, 245};
    int k;
    int h;
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        k = i + 1;
        h = k + 1; 
        line = new QuadCurve2D.Float(x[i], y[i], x[k], y[k], x[h], y[h]);
        g2.draw(line);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

"I figured this out after. i had to increment i by 3 in order to have the coordinates in the right spots. Simple fix. I was looking at it for too long!"